# How to set min interval for vAxis in Google charts?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a google chart which works fine if there is some data. But sometimes there is no data to show. In this case the vAxis automatically decides to show only 3 values: 0.0, 0.5 and 1.0. In my case it makes sense to show only integer numbers. So I tried to use

```
vAxis: { viewWindow: { min: 0 }, format: 0 }
```

But then it only rounds up and shows: 0, 1, 1. I'd rather need a min interval of 1 to see the values: 0, 1, 2 and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Please feel free to play around with this fiddle: [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/b4f4utL4/1/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to WhiteHat's suggestion here is my custom solution for this problem. I didn't find a simple way with some kind of google charts options but this is a simple workaround which does exactly what I need:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

var maxValue = 7;

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2017, 1, 1),  0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 2),  0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 3),  7],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 4),  0],
    [new Date(2017, 1, 5),  0],
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Test',
    legend: 'none',
    width: 450,
    height: 500
  };

options["vAxis"] = (maxValue < 5) ? { viewWindow: { min: 0 }, ticks: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] } :
                   (maxValue < 9) ? { viewWindow: { min: 0 }, ticks: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8] } :
                   (maxValue < 13) ? { viewWindow: { min: 0 }, ticks: [0, 3, 6, 9, 12] } : { viewWindow: { min: 0 } };

  var linearChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('div'));
  linearChart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
```